# Is there no option other than Apple Push Notification for sending a notification from a server to a client?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Its not possible to intercept SMSs with iOS, and its not possible to poll a server or permanently maintain an outstanding HTTP request from the device to a server (unless the app has a valid background mode).

Therefore if there is a requirement to push a notification from a server to the client, is it correct that there is no option other than to us APNS?

If there is a requirement to push a notification from a server to the device and not have the user receive an alert (in the situation when the application is in the background), then it seems this just isn't possible at all?

Is this correct. Are there any creative workarounds that are legitimate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct - there is no option but APNS for receiving notifications once an App is in the background.

There is no way to intercept ShortMessages (in background or not). There also is no possible  way to permanently poll a server when being in background (which is good because that would drain the battery as it does for Android apps).

Answer (score 1):

It could be possible if you can class your application as VOIP and use that background processing mode.

> If there is a requirement to push a notification from a server to the device and not have the user receive an alert (in the situation when the application is in the background), then it seems this just isn't possible at all?

If the user doesn't need to receive an immediate alert, can't you just poll the server when the application is started or comes to the foreground?

Comment: Yes you could - but if the server has information that should be pushed to the device immediatly and the application is not in the foreground (and the application is not VOIP) then there's no solution apparently.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  If your app is in the background and the user doesn't need to be notified, then the user will see the new data when they next open the app.  If your app polls when it comes to the foreground, then the user will see the new data when they next open the app.  What is the difference from the user's perspective?

Comment: The requirement is to notify the user there is new data and when they launch the app it has already downloaded. The payload of the data is larger than can be fit within an APN, so if a push notification is sent then when theylaunch the app the data still at that point needs to be downloaded - hence the user will experience a delay depending upon the connectivity conditions. The requirement is that they should experience no delay at all, thus I am trying to determine if there is any way of downloading the data *before* the user is notified of its existence.

Comment: The title and body of your question are both about pushing a notification, not downloading large amounts of data in the background.  Generally speaking, the more accurate you are in describing what it is you are doing, the better results you get from Stack Overflow.  [Describe the goal, not the step](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal).

Comment: The extra details about downloading data in the background were only added because somebody asked about them. My original question was and still is focused on pushing notifications options, I am not in this posting asking anything about downloading data nor running in the background. That is why I didn't mention it in the title nor body - in order to stay focused on pushing notification. I wanted to concentrate just upon push notications.

Comment: I know what your original question was, what I'm saying is that if you neglect to mention your *goal*, then you might be missing good advice.  If your goal is to get updated data onto the device and let the user know when he opens the app, then there could be solutions that don't involve notifications.  Conversely, people can suggest things that don't make sense in terms of the goal.  Did you read the link I gave?  You're handicapping yourself for no reason.